# Type hinting for multiple parameters of same type?

Tags: python, type-hinting

Is there another way to type hint parameters of the same type other than:

```
def foobar(a: int, b: int, c: int, d: str): ...
```

Maybe something like:

```
def foobar([a, b, c]: int, d: str): ...
```

Obviously notional, but something to reduce repeating type hints

Comment: Don't Repeat Yourself should be called Don't Be Redundant. Just because you are repeating something doesn't mean you don't have to (or shouldn't) repeat it.

Comment: @chepner Technically, there's no repeats here.  `a != b != c`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only ways that I know involve "packaging" the parameters in some way.

Due to how var-args work, you could shift your order a bit and take the arguments as var-args:

```
def foobar(d: str, *args: int): …
```

`args` now holds `a`, `b`, and `c` (along with whatever else is passed).

Along the same lines, you could pass in a list:

```
from typing import List

def foobar(args: List[int], d: str): …
```

Which is essentially the same as above.

Of course though, these both come with the **severe** drawback that you no longer have the ability to static-check arity; which is arguably even worse of a problem than not being able to static-check type.

You could mildly get around this by using a tuple to ensure length:

```
from typing import Tuple

def foobar(args: Tuple[int, int, int], d: str): …
```

But of course, this has just as much repetition as your original code (and requires packing the arguments into a tuple), so there's really no gain.

I do not know of any "safe" way to do literally what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Carcigenicate covered the topic pretty well, but since your concern is mostly notational and just want to make it look neat, you might consider using [hanging indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) instead:

```
def foobar(a: int,
           b: int,
           c: int,
           d: str):
    pass
```